# Making detail button always visible in iOS MapView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, view

I have a map view on my iOS app and i want to make detail button that when user press the pin icon visible without interaction. It should be visible when user open the map. Is it possible to make it? I use the code for showing annotation, I need it for button.

[image: callout image]

```
self.mapView.showAnnotations([destinationAnnotation], animated: true )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to show annotation once you load map. You can simply make annotation is "selected". While this is generally achieved by a user tapping on the annotation view (i.e. the pin), you can also programmatically "select" the annotation:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

When you add pin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select the mapView annoattion programmatically as:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated:false)
```